# How to Debug Unamanaged C++ code Included in Solution

Tags: c++, debugging, .net-4.0, pinvoke, swig

I am using a third-party, proprietary DLL for which the source code is not available to me. Wrapper code that appears to have been auto-generated using SWIG 1.3.39 is, however, available to me. The wrapper code consists of a C++ file that compiles (using some headers that describe the DLL) to a DLL and of a C# project that makes PInvoke calls to the C++ wrapper DLL.

Those C++ projects I have included in my project Solution , however when I set the break point in the C++ code , I never get there. When I try to F11 in my C#, to go inside the C++ function , I get "Show Assembly" instead.

I have trie **Solution > Proporties > Configuration Proporties** but don't find anything with the option to debug Unmanaged/Native Code.

**Edit**

The wrapper C++ code is available to me and I need to see the values I am passing from C# are actually getting passed to the C# code .

```
// In one file of the C# wrapper:
public string GetKey()
{
    // swigCPtr is a HandleRef to an object already created
    string ret = csWrapperPINVOKE.mdMUHybrid_GetKey(swigCPtr);
    return ret;
}

// In the csWrapperPINVOKE class in another file in the C# wrapper:
[DllImport("csWrapper.dll", EntryPoint="CSharp_mdMUHybrid_GetKey")]
public static extern StringBuilder mdMUHybrid_GetKey(HandleRef jarg1);
```

And the C++ code from the C++ wrapper .

```
SWIGEXPORT char * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_mdMUHybrid_GetKey(void * jarg1) {
  char * jresult ;
  mdMUHybrid *arg1 = (mdMUHybrid *) 0 ;
  char *result = 0 ;

  arg1 = (mdMUHybrid *)jarg1; 
  result = (char *)(arg1)->GetKey();
  jresult = SWIG_csharp_string_callback((const char *)result); 
  return jresult;
}
```

Now As I am trying to pass `swigCPtr` from the C# wrapper by using `csWrapperPINVOKE.mdMUHybrid_GetKey(swigCPtr);`

Now I want to see if jarg1 is getting the value from swigCPtr;

```
SWIGEXPORT char * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_mdMUHybrid_GetKey(void * jarg1) {
  char * jresult ;
  mdMUHybrid *arg1 = (mdMUHybrid *) 0 ;
  char *result = 0 ;

  arg1 = (mdMUHybrid *)jarg1; 
  result = (char *)(arg1)->GetKey();
  jresult = SWIG_csharp_string_callback((const char *)result); 
  return jresult;
}
```

Comment: There's not much point in debugging native code if you don't have the source code for it.  Nothing to look at but machine code, nothing you can do fix any problems.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have the C++ wrapper code with me and I want to see the values passed from C# are actually reflected in wrapper function. Updated the code for reference

Answer (score 0):

When you have a managed exe and want to debug the native DLL it uses you need to tell the debugger about that. Don't use the Debugger Type **Auto**, what's the default. Use **Mixed** instaed.

The auto will identify the managed exe and allowes managed debugging. That's not what you need to debug native C++ code.

You find the *Debugger Type* setting in the *Debugging* section of the project properties.